# Vim: save a macro inside a mapping

Tags: vim, macros

I have a mapping, like `<leader>x` and inside that mapping it does some moderately complex work. I'd like that mapping, as part of its work, to save a macro, so that I can then use `@z` (or whatever) afterwards to repeat it.

I know it's a bit odd to want a shortcut for something that is already a shortcut, but bear with me (:

My real example is a bit complicated, so let's just use a simple one here:

Here's a working mapping:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>x 'mz' . v:count . 'Ax<ESC>' . v:count . 'Ix<ESC>`z'
```

I can use this by typing `10,x` in normal mode, and it will both append and prepend 10 `x` characters to the current line, returning me to where I was.

That works fine.

What I'd like to do is this: First run `10,x`, as before, but then have that sequence of work be stored in the `q` register as a macro, so I can run `@q` to repeat it.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>x 'qqmz' . v:count . 'Ax<ESC>' . v:count . 'Ix<ESC>`zq'
```

As you can see, I just added `qq` at the start (to begin recording a macro in the `q` register), and a final `q` at the end, to stop the macro recording.

If I type out these commands by hand, it works fine.

But when I have them inside `nnoremap`, it does not work.

What's going on here?

Comment: Why not just  do `qq10,xq`?

Comment: @PeterRincker Yeah, that's what I've been doing (: This just was bugging me so wanted to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already figured out why this approach isn't working for you, because of `q` being disabled in mappings. Here is how you can get around it:

```
nnoremap <leader>x :<C-u>let @q='mz'.v:count.'Ax<C-v><ESC>'.v:count.'Ix<C-v><ESC>`z'<CR>@q
```

This simply enters the command you want directly into register 'q', and then afterwards runs it.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround — not too terrible, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I missed this in the docs:

> The 'q' command is disabled while executing a register, and it doesn't
>   work inside a mapping and |:normal|.

(from `:help q`)

I guess what I want is just not possible without getting into vimscript, etc.